# Provide user defined functions for derivative values

Tags: php, sql, drupal-8

Currently we are storing values to our database. Those values have a name and they have a unit. They might be used for example to create different graphs.

For example a country could have an unemployment rate of 5%. Thus we store a value 5, having the name "unemployment rate" and connecting a unit "percent".

In future our users should be able to derive new values by entering a function f(x), where f(x) is executed either when new (base-)values are imported or a new value with a new function is created.

I have some ideas how to implement this but all have some security loop holes. Now I'd like you guys to ask how you would approach this?

1. Thus how would you allow to enter a user a function f(x) in the user interface
2. How could the function be possibly stored
3. And finally how would you execute the function (in a sandboxed environment) to get the derived value for storing it.

Of course I am not expecting a detailed implementation but rather an approach to execute a user defined function without letting users compromising the system.

**Update:** Database can be chosen from any Drupal 8 [compatible](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/install-requirements.html#_database) - SQLight might not be the best option though ;)

Here is the list:

- MySQL - 5.5.3 (MariaDB 5.5.20, Percona 5.5.8) or higher with an
  InnoDB-compatible primary storage engine
- PostgreSQL - 9.1.2 or higher
- SQLite - 3.4.2 or higher

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is very tricky, and it depends a lot on the underlying database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the db options